# how to verify ssl certificate by php

Tags: php, .net, ssl-certificate

I want to verify `https://pep.shaparak.ir` ssl certificate by php.

but I dont know how ??

I found this snippet:

> System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
>   delegate(object sender,
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate
>   certificate, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain
>   chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)

but that is for `.net` and I dont know what is equivalent of it in `php` ??

Comment: How are you making the HTTP request?

Comment: I make  HTTP request by `curl`. should I make requests in other way ??

Comment: Have you found a solutions? I have similar questions :(